# Java8 - Asynchronous execution of independent code

Tags: java-8

**Java8** - In my portal, on the page (Homepage) which gets displayed after Customer logs in, I need to display multiple sections like,
    Order details, Available invoices, Catalog pdf etc.

There is no dependency between these sections, just need each section data to display on the front end.

If I try to get these data sequentially on the back end, it takes time to display the Homepage.

I'm looking at speeding up this process, I could think of:

- Instead of trying to get all details after login on the back end, I will first display the Homepage, then make individual ajax calls for each section using jQuery.
- Use forkjoinpool (RecursiveTask) on the back end and fire up recursive tasks for each section

I prefer doing it on the back end (business tier), Is there any other solution available on Java8 to acheive this task? Looking at calling asynchronously every section logic instead of sequential flow.

Comment: Try using `CompletableFuture` with a custom executor. If you need more information, you'd need to post your current code.

Comment: The best from user perspective would be the ajax callbacks, like in a SPA. User will receive update when view is ready. With CompletableFuture (concurrent backend solution) you need to wait for all results to be ready, so a single resource will block other. But as @ernest_k mentioned: it depends also on your code and used frameworks.

Comment: Before deciding for a solution, you should identify the actual problem. If getting the data sequentially takes a long time, it might be due to the data transfer over the network, as in most cases. In that case, no parallel processing on the server can fix the issue.